# Get address book using doveadm

Tags: dovecot

I want to get the address book list using `doveadm`. I have searched so many documents, but I'm unable to find it. Please guide me, how to get it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address book is not a part of IMAP server and provided by 3rd-party services like LDAP. So you have to dig in some other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot is an IMAP server. Address books are not part of what IMAP does.